# Change password functionality in ASP.NET MVC(unable to fetch value from database)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an MVC application. I am getting a null value in variable when I fetching data from database.

Here is my change password view code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Changepassword", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

       <table class="center">


           <tr>
               <td>Old Password</td>
               <td>
                   @Html.EditorFor(pass => pass.Password)
               </td>
               <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(pass => pass.Password)</td>
           </tr>
           <tr class="rowspace">
               <td>New Password</td>

               <td>
                   @Html.EditorFor(pass => pass.NewPassword)
               </td>
               <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(pass => pass.NewPassword)</td>
           </tr>

           <tr class="rowspace">
               <td colspan="3" id="button">
                   <input type="submit" value="Change Password" /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr class="rowspace"><td colspan="3">@ViewBag.Message</td></tr>
       </table>

}
```

Here is my Home controller code.

**Problem I am facing - var userDetail is returning null and when i checked and debug my code using breakpoint my login.Email is not fetching email from database and it is returning null.**

```
public ActionResult Changepassword(tblUser login)
{
   using (UserDetailsEntities db = new UserDetailsEntities())
   {
       var detail = db.tblUsers.Where(log => log.Password == login.Password).FirstOrDefault();
       if (detail != null)
       {
           var userDetail = db.tblUsers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Email == login.Email);


           if (userDetail != null)
           {
               userDetail.Password = login.NewPassword;

               db.SaveChanges();
               ViewBag.Message = "Record Inserted Successfully!";
           }
           else
           {
               ViewBag.Message = "Password not Updated!";
           }

       }
   }

   return View(login);
}
```

Comment: in your view for the model email is not assigned.so it will come as null in `tblUser login` make a hidden field for the email..

Comment: And are you really storing your passwords in the database as plain text (not hashed)?

Comment: @Sachu can you explain with code .... as I am very new to MVC and coding.It will be very helpful

Comment: @AmanM two ways of doing it..1. Like you are asking old password ask for the email in the view. Or pass the model from controller and save the email value in a hidden field.I hope first one is the best practice.

Comment: Just add `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email)` in your view and change the controller to `var detail = db.tblUsers.Where(x => x.Password == login.Password && x.Email == login.Email).FirstOrDefault();` - the second query is not required

Comment: MVC has a bunch of boilerplate code for user/password management, including password changing and password resetting. It's much more secure than this approach, as it doesn't store the password in plaintext in your database, which is one of the main ways that passwords get hacked. If you are writing this for an exercise, that's fine, but if this is meant to go anywhere near the real internet, you shouldn't be doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

In your view email for the model is not assigning so it will be always null when its get posted. 
Best practice is to ask for the email also at the time of password change. Check code below
**Your view**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Changepassword", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
           <table class="center">
             <tr>
                   <td>Email</td>
                   <td>
                       @Html.EditorFor(pass => pass.email)
                   </td>
                   <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(pass => pass.email)</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Old Password</td>
                   <td>
                       @Html.EditorFor(pass => pass.Password)
                   </td>
                   <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(pass => pass.Password)</td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="rowspace">
                   <td>New Password</td>

                   <td>
                       @Html.EditorFor(pass => pass.NewPassword)
                   </td>
                   <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(pass => pass.NewPassword)</td>
               </tr>

               <tr class="rowspace">
                   <td colspan="3" id="button">
                       <input type="submit" value="Change Password" /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="rowspace"><td colspan="3">@ViewBag.Message</td></tr>
           </table>

    }
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Changepassword(tblUser login)
    {
       using (UserDetailsEntities db = new UserDetailsEntities())
       {
           var detail = db.tblUsers.Where(log => log.Password == login.Password 
           && log.email == login.email).FirstOrDefault();
           if (detail != null)
           {
                   userDetail.Password = login.NewPassword;

                   db.SaveChanges();
                   ViewBag.Message = "Record Inserted Successfully!";

              }
     else
               {
                   ViewBag.Message = "Password not Updated!";
               }


       }

       return View(login);
    }
```